# CloudWatch logs delayed for a lambda function

Tags: lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

It seems that I have a delay with the CloudWatch log of one of my lambda function's.
I have a lambda function that gets triggered by a Kinesis stream. The lambda function writes records into a DynamoDB table.

I know for sure that the lambda function gets executed since I see new records in the DynamodDB table. But the CloudWatch log doesn't get updated. I waited for almost an hour and there is no update.

Also, permissions are good since I have older records in my log.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CloudWatch does sometimes have a slight delay, but if you've waited an hour, it probably isn't going to show up.  Double-check permissions to ensure they haven't changed. From the Lambda Management Console, do you still see "Amazon CloudWatch Logs" on the right as seen in the picture below?

[image]

If not, double check your security policy to make sure you have allowed CreateLogGroup, CreateLogStream, and PutLogEvents.  Here is a snippet of a policy that includes the appropriate permissions.

```
"Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
          "logs:CreateLogGroup",
          "logs:CreateLogStream",
          "logs:PutLogEvents"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
      }
    ]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is very usefull, but all allowed permissions and sill waiting too much time to create the logs =/